# key estimate "in" establishing or key estimate "to" establishing

Tags: grammar, prepositions, difference

I am struggling to decide which sentence is correct (maybe they are both correct?) and I would appreciate any comments.

The sentences I am trying to decide between are

> The following result was the key estimate to establishing the main result in ...
>
> The following result was the key estimate in establishing the main result in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence would be better as

> The following result was the key estimate to ***establish*** the main result
>   in ...

The second sentence would be better as

> The following result was the key estimate ***for*** establishing the main
>   result in ...

I can't quote sources, this is my supposition as a native BrE speaker.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use adjectival **[key](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22was%20key%20to%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)**:

> The following estimate was key to establishing the main result in ...

No article.

Comment: Isn't **key** a noun here? It is an adjective in the question, or if you insist "adjectival".

Comment: @Weather Vane: **key** is a noun in your examples but here it is an adjective, a synonym of "crucial".

Comment: No, **key** in my answer is an adjective. It qualifies the noun "estimate".

Comment: You're right. I was going from memory. I though you had written "the key to establish". But it's an adjective in my example.

Comment: Thank you for the eddication, I never heard the word **adjectival** in my whole long life.

Comment: @Weather Vane: You must not be hanging out where the fun happens.